# Best way to heat sink many resistors

Tags: heat, led-strip, dfm

I have a PCB design with a long row of 1206 power resistors. Although only a few of them will be active at a time, they can dissipate up to 1 watt each, so I would like to heat sink them. If they get too hot they may overheat the components they're connected to, or just fail sooner.

Picture for reference:

[image: pcb image]

For electrical and space reasons I can't attach either pad of the resistors to a large plane. I've placed thermal pads under the resistors, but they cannot be electrically connected to it, only thermally.

My original plan was to "pour" thermal epoxy over the resistors after reflow assembly, this would spread the heat out from the active resistors, and also couple it into the nearby thermal pads. I tested that, and it works, but the issue is that the epoxy is much thicker than I anticipated (like frosting). This makes smearing it onto the board without covering adjacent LEDs quite difficult and time consuming, not really suitable for production.

I also considered placing a dab of thermal compound (not epoxy) under each resistor before reflow, but the issue with that is that the thermal compound must be able to withstand reflow temperatures. I [found one](https://www.matterhackers.com/store/l/boron-nitride-thermal-paste/sk/MRH0MS03) (boron nitride), but it's a very watery consistency and it dries to a crust in seconds, so that also proved to be impractical.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to heatsink these resistors?

Comment: The usual way to heatsink SMD parts that don't have a dedicated thermal pad is through the contacts, with large copper areas on the PCB adjacent to them.

Comment: 1. split the resistors into two (calls for new layout) or use higher wattage resistor (https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/rohm-semiconductor/LTR18EZPFU10L0/RHM1227TR-ND/4052971)

Comment: Epoxy is a thermal insulator, how do you know chip temp?

Comment: A higher wattage resistor won't prevent other issues with dissipating that much heat. Won't affect the resistors but the other parts may still have issues with that heat. @user323693

Comment: Have you considered through hole resistors mounted in the air?

Comment: Also are you sure those are 1 watt resistors? Have you looked at the datasheet for the recommended pad size to maintain the temperature?

Comment: You must rethink your overall design for efficiency and not have to lose 1W per R or 45W total. that would need a CPU cooler.

Comment: Why 1W? ........those are 0.5W max parts that ought to be derated .

Comment: How powerful are these LEDs and how hard are you driving them?  1 Watt is a silly big amount of power to waste to regulate an LED, high power LEDs are usually current controlled and driven with switched mode drivers for that reason.  Are the resistors just series resistors for the LEDs or are they something else?

Comment: They are series resistors. The LEDs are PWM controlled with daisy chainable drivers, but worst case scenario they can be turned on 100%. The voltage drop is wasteful but necessary to keep the LED brightness consistent if the bus voltage or forward voltages change slightly.

Comment: Actual epoxy is thin and runny; the viscosity comes from filler (typically fumed silica but can be just about anything like sawdust). Just get marine epoxy (West Systems should be easy to find but there are cheaper alternatives)

Comment: Your LED supply should be 3.3V 2% then after verifying LED consistency for 3.0 to 3.1V , compute R for the 200 to 300mV drop  with 10% of the LED power... batches of LEDs tend to be within 5% if good in 5050 LEDs for Vf at nominal current.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's thermal epoxy, so it has some kind of powdered ceramic filler. I don't think regular epoxy would be thermally conductive enough.

Answer (score 2):

One cleaner way to go is to use a thermal pad. Those come into sheets that you can cut to the appropriate size, you can then screw an aluminum heatsink to it. There is a [long thin heatsink](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/advanced-thermal-solutions-inc/ATS-EXL66-300-R0/5848392?utm_adgroup=Thermal%20-%20Heat%20Sinks&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Fans%2C%20Thermal%20Management&utm_term=&utm_content=Thermal%20-%20Heat%20Sinks&gclid=Cj0KCQiAs5eCBhCBARIsAEhk4r5di-TD2u7w0ORU9ZcTq8e3gATfzTNmkSwuIPRmq1O8hdYUULmsMlsaAt7EEALw_wcB) that would fit there.

[image]

The advantage of this method is that you don't have to do anything special for the SMT process and can be mounted afterward. It also avoids the mess of using epoxy / thermal compound, can be disassembled easily.

These pads come in different thicknesses from less than a millimeter to 5mm, so it "squeezes" when compressed, allowing for small height differences between components.

If you cannot afford screws, 3M manufactures a [thermal pad](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/3m-(tc)/16.51MM-16.51MM-10-8810/2649856?utm_adgroup=Thermal%20-%20Pads%2C%20Sheets&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Fans%2C%20Thermal%20Management_NEW&utm_term=&utm_content=Thermal%20-%20Pads%2C%20Sheets&gclid=Cj0KCQiAs5eCBhCBARIsAEhk4r7T5Xlr4lxM9JFSQSXBcectEONiWUM4HWOFjDlJgfORjkfsOgAMmUcaAkY3EALw_wcB) that is sticky on both sides. I've been using that for years and yet one has come apart. It also comes in sheets that you can cut.

[image]

Comment: Are these pads you recommend electrical insulators?

Comment: That’s what I was thinking at first but if there is 45W load, not a chance to get low Rth on non-coplanar SMD’s with 1W/sqin extrusion 1-sided using tape

Comment: Yes they are insulators @KH

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 OP said " Although only a few of them will be active at a time". Also these pads comes in different thickness so it can handle some variance in height, but screws would be a better solution.

Comment: Keep in mind the best 1206 is rated for 0.5W @ 125’C with a 70’C ambient on next chip.  The heatsink would need to be as wide as the board unless by a few you mean 3 max

Comment: OP doesn't specify thermal output, for how long. I think if OP stuff was working by just pouring some thermal epoxy around or thermal compound to the PCB, it should work with the heatsink.

Comment: What is on the other side of the PCB? | Is this a small or high volume product. An aluminium core PCB may be in order.

Comment: The other side is almost entirely exposed copper. It will be mounted on a heatsink. Tony, only a few resistors at a time will be dissipating 1W, not all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Think outside the box.

If you're shedding that much power in the dropping resistors that you're exceeding the rating, consider a separate, lower VDD rail for the LEDs, made with a DC-DC step-down converter. Then you can optimize the voltage so that the resistor values can be lower, and therefore shed less heat for the given current.

Efficiency will be better and heat will be less. Win-win overall.

Also, do your LEDs need cooling? I'm guessing they do. Consider a thermal solution on the back of your board using thermal vias and a heatsink. Maybe mount the whole board to the sink with a thermal pad in between. If you have no backside components that would be easy to do.

Comment: There is a thermal solution on the back of the board, the LEDs are connected to it. The voltage drop is unfortunately necessary to even out and differences in LED forward voltage. The high currents can also cause voltage drop in the planes, and I don't want the LEDs to be noticeably effected if the bus voltage goes down by 100mV.

Comment: Are your drivers current sources? If so, then this will do the compensating for you. Something to consider.

Comment: The daisy chainable drivers can be used that way (WS2811s), but I need to drive much higher current than the WS2811 is capable of, so I'm buffering the output with mosfets.

Comment: You may need to go as far as having separate supplies tuned for each color's Vf. Then you can use minimum series dropping. At the power levels you're contemplating it might be worth it.